# Get value from custom field checkout woocommerce to function wp

Tags: php

I need help, i need to add fe if custom field from checkout have specific value.
How add billing_city value in  function custom_fee.
billing_city is a custom field added from check-out editor.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'custom_fee', 20, 1 );
function custom_fee ( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( ! ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) )
        return;

    if ( 'city name' == $city) {
       $surcharge = $cart->subtotal + 5;
        $cart->add_fee( '', $surcharge, true );
   }
}

// jQuery - Update checkout on methode payment change  
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_jqscript' );
function custom_checkout_jqscript() {
    if ( ! ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) )
        return; // Only checkout page
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        $('form.checkout').on('change', 'select[name="billing_city"]', function(){
            $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');

        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```